# Theming Custom Plugin Page

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I am creating a plugin that collects user information. It's a bunch of forms.

So, the user will hit the first form page, enter data, then be redirected to the second form page, where they enter more data. There's 3 forms, and a "Thank You" page at the end.

Each of the 4 pages must use the same theme that is current installed on the users Wordpress. So each page has the standard header, footer etc. If the user changes their theme, the form pages included with my plugin will be consistent with the users theme.

So if the user visits: http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/includes/page1.php it will show my form page that looks consistent with the rest of their site. I obviously create a rewrite rule to these scripts, but the above URL was to demonstrate what I mean.

How do I do this? By page, I mean a standard HTML/PHP page, not the Wordpress definition of a page.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Question is too confusing.

Comment: Ok give me a moment

Comment: There is no way your form will ever be styling compatiple will all themes as you can never know which styling methods and selectors is used by a theme

Comment: @PieterGoosen if that's not possible what other solutions are? I've edited my question to give a bit more detail.

Comment: Do not create a page yourself, create a shortcode which the user can then add into a page which he will create.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have created a shortcode for the first form, which is a search type box the user can place anywhere. But when I process that form, I need to redirect them to the second form etc. If I create shortcodes for the 2nd and 3rd form pages that would mean I have no way of knowing what those pages are in the script to redirect to them because I don't know what pages the user has placed them on. If that makes sense.

Comment: Create one shortcode and one page, and let that specific page handle the complete process together with your shortcode. It is going to getting tricky, as you will need to save/set GET or POST variables, check for their existance, and based on that, fail the form that was filled, or move over to the next section.